# Roberta detokenization without losing labels

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

So I ran a custom Roberta Token Classification, and I have a tokenized output id that looks like this, each of the output ID's has a corresponding label.

```
  Ġlives   
  Ġo
  Ġn
  ĠCali
```

Each of these tokens comes with its prediction label. Detokenizing the text is trivial, but it loses the match with the prediction labels.

```
detokenized = ''.join(tokens).replace('Ġ', ' ')
```

However, the challenge is to match the labels to the detokenized text. if anyone can point me to a script or method to use to solve this problem, would be really nice. Also below is my prediction script which was modified from a BERT script.

```
tags, t_words = [], []                                         #tokenize
for row in test_df:
  tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.encode(row)
  input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenized_sentence]).cuda()

  with torch.no_grad():                                                 #predict
    output = model(input_ids)
    label_indices = np.argmax(output[0].to('cpu').numpy(), axis=2)

     # join split tokens
    new_tokens, new_labels = [], []
    tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids.to('cpu').numpy()[0] )
    for token, label_idx in zip(tokens, label_indices[0]):
        new_labels.append(tag_values[label_idx])
        new_tokens.append(token)
    tags.append(new_labels)
    t_words.append(new_tokens)
```

but is there any way to have the prediction labels match the detokenized inputs, else the entire attempt at prediction is pointless.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? So, you have `tokens=['Ġlives','Ġo','Ġn', 'ĠCali']`, right? Do you have any other input? What is the expected output?

Comment: Sample tokens = 'Ġlives','Ġi','Ġn', 'ĠCali', Ġfor, Ġnia.]

Comment: Ok, but what is the expected output?

Comment: Sample tokens = 'Ġlives','Ġi','Ġn', 'ĠCali', Ġfor, Ġnia.]                                                              label indices = ' 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1                                                                                                     What i want is this: [lives in California ],[ 0 , 0, 1]

Comment: If you have `tokens = ['Ġlives','Ġi','Ġn', 'ĠCali', 'Ġfor', 'Ġnia.']`, then how can you find out where the spaces should be introduced? Your labels contain no details on that, and your `Ġ` does not signal word continuation or end. Had you used SentencePiece, it would be easy.

Comment: Is sentence piece tokenization different from the regular Roberta tokenizer?

Comment: SP privides a roundtrip tokenization-detokenization process. Not sure I see a way with your inputs.

Comment: is there a way i can use sentence piece, pass it through roberta model and return it back to sentence piece. if you have any link to a repo, i would like to try it. my input is a two label custom NER. the output is either 0, 1 or 2., and the training dataset was prepared in the format by myself. it worked okay with BERT too, as the output tokens were whole words masked.

Comment: You may read about [SentencePiece here](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece), it is  framework agnostic. I only used it with TensorFlow and OpenNMT.

Comment: How do you get the corrosponding labels to the output ID's? Are the output id's are part of the roberta tokenizer vocabulary?

Comment: @cronoik I prepared a training set with sentences broken into a single word per row and the word's accompanying label. This is par for the course in NER and Token classification. Then I trained this dataset. and then i passed in a dataset for prediction. so the Roberta tokenizer uses its own style to tokenize my dataset and while it does a good job of labelling, the output is kinda useless to me if the individual tokens are not meaningful.  each token has an accompanying label, and while its easy to detokenize ,  i need to modify the labels to match the output of detokenization

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so i went to take a look at Robertas repo, and they specifically say that i cannot use sentence piece as i am only finetuning. it would have been possible if i were pretraining from scratch though

Comment: Ok, so the question remains: how do you know the item in the list is a starting word chunk?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the detokenizer does a pretty good job, it detokenizes the sentence as a whole and stores it as a whole string. only i lose the labels.

Comment: Can you please give us a reporducible example (post your model class, how you initiate it and an sample input)?